# Lithium Standard Electrode Potential is (-)3 Volt. They why Lithium based batteries have a nominal voltage of 3.8 V?

Tags: voltage, lithium-ion, electrode

The title sums it up, why there is this difference?

Comment: What's the other electrode?

Comment: The standard hydrogen electrode (with potential equal to 0) is the cathode

Comment: Lithium based batteries don't use standard hydrogen electrodes, do they?

Comment: There are loads of different types of Lithium batteries with different cell voltages, and there are plenty of articles about them you should easily be able to find online.

Comment: Yeah @user253751, Lithium based battery don't use standard hydrogen electrode. That was my question flaw. It is all clear now

Comment: I suggest you clarify your question to refer specifically to Lithium-Ion batteries or LiFE, whichever you're actually thinking about.  As-is, your question is both unclear and too broad.  As far as my understanding goes, the zero-current voltage of a cell is the *difference* between the electrochemical potential of the anode and the cathode; "lithium" only refers to the predominant element used, because metallic lithium doesn't work as an electrode, it doesn't even refer to the actual chemical compounds that makes up the electrodes.

Answer (score 2):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_battery)

Depending on the design and chemical compounds used, lithium cells can produce voltages from 1.5 V (comparable to a zinc–carbon or alkaline battery) to about 3.7 V.